# ErrOR 0x80072efd when sending an Http request to rest api on Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator

Tags: httprequest, windows-phone-8.1, emulation, dotnet-httpclient, hyper-v

I'm currently working on a Windows Phone 8.1 app, my first one actually. I would like to send through my emulator windows phone 8.1, a http request to a remote server. So I've used that code:

```
 try
 {
   mailToCheck.MailProfil = TxtBox_mail.Text.ToString();
   string js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mailToCheck);
   HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept",       "Application/JSON");

   HttpRequestMessage data = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("url");
   data.Content = new HttpStringContent((js));
   HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(data).AsTask();
   string statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
  }catch (Exception ex)
  {

  }
```

and I'm always getting that error : 0x80072efd.
I've heard of it means that there is no internet connexion but I'm able to navigate on website on the emulator web browser. The Networking capability is checked. Does somebody already faced that issue ? Maybe the Hyper-V blocking ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Avoid obfuscating your question too much.  There is no capability named "Networking", there is no server that you are going to connect to with "url".

Comment: Come on man, there are no thousands of capabilities and only one which concerns networking, only one ID_CAP_NETWORKING and I won't give the url as the server is not secured. The server works perfectly on get method as well on post from IOS or Android emulator, any browsers also...

Comment: Does that happend with every URI, or only with one specific URI?

Comment: Yes, it happens with every URI. As the Http request should work, I've created a new page with a WebBrowser control and tried to reach google.com and it doesn't work so the internet connection from the app is obviously not working. Again the ID_CAP_NETWORKING is enabled and I can navigate on the web  from internet explorer on the emulator. Does someone know if there are some configuration to do in the Hyper-V ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all the solutions proposed all over the web, I couldn't figure out how to solve that problem. All the following didn't work at all:
- Cleaning of the virtual machines on Hyper-V
- Disable/Able Hyper-V
- Repair the SDK with visual studio repair tool.
- Re-install Visual Studio 2013 update 2.
Still not working the **Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch - 512 MB**. Somehow, I've tried to launch my project on the **Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch** and it works magically. My trials to solve that problem took a lot of time and came to nothing. So my advise is to use the following emulator: **Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch**.
The difference between these emulators is about the memory allowed for the app, if you use **Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch** just be careful about performance management for low performance devices as Lumia 520 for example.