# Send request & Get Response in Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I  have  migrated  from  Windows Phone 8 Silverlight  to  Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT.
`HttpWebRquest` and  `WebClient` used  in  WP 8 Silverlight.
Wp 8.0  silverlight ,i  have  used  webclient..

```
 webClntRech.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://wallet.net.co.in/services/bi/rechargedownload/01/0001/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmssms") + "/504434"));

            webClntRech.DownloadStringCompleted += webClntRech_DownloadStringCompleted;
```

**I  want  similar  functionality in WInrt 8.1**

I  can't  find  `WebClient` in  WinRT. I  came  across `HttpClient`.

As based  on  requirement, we  have  to  implement POST Method  for  all  requests. I  followed  some  examples  and  got  this  code..which  is  not  working..

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string ResponceResult = await client.PostAsync("http://wallet.net.co.in/services/bi/rechargedownload/01/0001/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmssms") + "/504434",);

 MessageDialog m = new MessageDialog(ResponceResult);
        await m.ShowAsync();
```

**The  response  will  be  in  Json  Format.**

I'm not  familiar  with  HTTP Content parameter  of `PostAynsc()` Method.

Went  through  several links. Can't  get  any  help.
How  to  implement it..

Comment: 1st your url is invalid check your url first

Comment: [How to connect to an HTTP server using Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn440594.aspx)

Comment: @Umar Ali   the  link  clearly   explains  Get  method  request..  My  requirement is  to  Use  only  Post Method..Thank you

Comment: Please check  Updated  Question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to change your url i.e: http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all

and then try this

[sending an Http request to rest api on Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26882745/3808469)

i hope this is helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

I use this utility method to POST JSON

```
 async void PostJson(string URL, string json)
 {
     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
     httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 25600000;

     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");

     HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(URL), new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     string responseAsText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     Dictionary<string, string> responseJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseAsText);
 }
```

**Update**

In order to just get JSON from URL, you can use the following code:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

// Deserialize JSON
MyObject myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(response);
```

Comment: For Url Parameter,i will  pass URL.for   Json  parameter..  what  i  have  to  pass..@M.Hassan

Comment: Anything that you need to post. e.g. I post several parameters (Category, Location etc.) to get corresponding data from server.

Comment: can i send  blank  parameter

Comment: Sure. Depends entirely on how server handles it. In my case, I get default data (without any filtration) in return.

Comment: Please describe what you need to post to server? Or are you just trying to get JSON from specific URL.

Comment: Just getting Json  response  from that URL

Comment: I  need  to  send  POST  request.  whether it  will  send  POST  request

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this with `HttpClient`

```
public async Task<string> httpClient(object param, Uri targetUri, string key)
    {
        using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(param);
            FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, jsonData)
            });
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(targetUri, content);
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

you can modified it any way you want

I used `Task` instead of void so I can await the result and later I deserialized it in another method